# Which database to use when developing a desktop application using java

Tags: java, database

Please suggest me to use the best database when developing a desktop application using java.

I am planning to develop a student information system where i want to store and retrieve student information. I will be using java swing to develop the system. Can anybody suggest me the best DB to use for my application.

Comment: Best is hard, but I'd recommend MySQL.

Comment: There's no best database in the world otherwise there wouldn't be so many RDBMS around there. With the current description in your question, you could use a RDBMS like MySQL or Postgre or maybe JavaDB (Derby), but the definition will depend on what you really need.

Comment: I actually want an opensource database, which will be easy to develop and deploy in the client system

Comment: Still not precise enough...

Comment: How about making you application work with all databases? most of DBMS provide a `JDBC` interface. Just stick with SQL standard and everything will be fine. If you want to do specific stuff, like date comparison or string concatenation you might create a builder witch creates appropriate satement-parts. Or you could just use a JPA implementation.

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is incredibly subjective, so let's narrow it down to some other criterion like lightweight and easily integrated.  In that category you could choose [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) or [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).  These systems are written in Java so you can integrate them straight into your application without the need to install, set up and maintain a server, which will make distribution and setup easier, and they have a decent feature set and performance.  From an ease of use for your end users that's about as simple as it will get.

The H2 webpage contains a small comparison stable that can help you select the "best" fit for your requirements.